# How to solve "In fread(text = .) : Discarded single-line footer while importing .txt file

Tags: r, import, fread

when I import my .txt data I get the following error message:

```
"3: In fread(text = .) :
  Discarded single-line footer: <<"2306956";1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;"22-208-2082-83";2008-11-07;"208";2082;0;NA;0"2306957";12;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;"22-208-2082-43";2008-11-07;"208";2082;0;NA;0"2306958";13;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;"22-208-2082-34";2008-11-07;"208";2082;0;NA;0"2306959";22;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;"22-208-2082-58";2008-11-07;"208";2082;0;NA;0"2306960";33;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;"22-208-2082-75";2008-11-07;"208";2082;1;2009->>"
```

The result is, that there will be missing data (Some entries are NA) in my tibble. Does anyone know where the problem is? I've already tried "In fread(text = ., fill = TRUE). Btw, I don`t need the first column.

My code is:

```
T22 <- read_file("Einzelteil_T22.txt") %>%  #Textdatei einlesen
  
  str_replace_all(. , 'NA\"', 'NA"\"') %>%  #Ersetzen des Trennsymbols "" durch neue Zeile
  str_replace_all(. , '\t', ';') %>%
  str_replace_all(. , '\"\"', '\n\"') %>%
  fread(text = .) %>%                      #Einlesen der neu strukturierten Daten in R-Studio
  as_tibble()                               #formatiert urspr?nglichen data.table-Dateityp in tbl_df Dateityp
  colnames(T22)[23] <- "Fehlerhaft_Fahrleistung"
T22$V1 <- NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an error? It looks like a warning - and only a warning that the last line will be skipped - perhaps nothing to worry about if the last line is blank or not data. To really help, I think we'd need a (small) sample of your data. Could you share enough of the input that would become the first 3 lines and the last 3 lines?